# SortedList<> and its strange setters

Tags: c#, .net, setter, sortedlist

I initially had some code, which when simplified, looks like this:

```
var planets = new List<Planet>
{
    new Planet {Id = 1, Name = "Mercury"},
    new Planet {Id = 2, Name = "Venus"},
};
```

I got into a scenario where the list was being populated all at once, but the reads weren't fast enough. And so, I changed this to use a SortedList instead.

I later realized that I could rewrite it like this

```
var planets = new SortedList<int, Planet>
{
    {1, new Planet {Id = 1, Name = "Mercury"}},
    {2, new Planet {Id = 2, Name = "Venus"}},
    //in my actual code, i am reading the ids from a db
};
```

But before I got to this approach, I had the code written like this

```
var planets = new SortedList<int, Planet>
{
    Keys = {1, 2},
    Values =
    {
        new Planet {Id = 1, Name = "Mercury"},
        new Planet {Id = 2, Name = "Venus"},
    }
};
```

which gives me this exception

```
System.NotSupportedException: This operation is not supported on SortedList
nested types because they require modifying the original SortedList.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.KeyList.Add(TKey key)
```

which I found to be very strange, coz IMHO, I wasn't really modifying the "original SortedList" as it claims, and what "nested types" is it talking about? Is it the list of keys internal to the `SortedList`?

I see then that the `Keys` and `Values` properties in `SortedList` don't actually have setters. They are read-only properties, and yet, I don't get a compile-time error. I am allowed to make a set call, as I can see in the stack trace with `KeyList.Add`. I feel the only reason why this fails is because of an explicit check within `SortedList`, which seems bizarre to me!

For instance
`var str = new String {Length = 0};` gives me a compile-time error as expected, since Length is a read-only property, as does `planets.Keys = null;`

Someone please tell me - what simple fact am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you've written is comparable to this:

```
var planets = new SortedList<int, Planet>();
planets.Keys.Add(1);
planets.Keys.Add(2);
planets.Values.Add(new Planet { Id = 1, Name = "Mercury" });
planets.Values.Add(new Planet { Id = 2, Name = "Venus" });
```

`SortedList` requires that you add the value and key at the same time via `SortedList<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)` method, so that it can sort the value by the key. The implementation of the `IList<T>` which is used for `Keys` and `Values` internally does not support adding a respective key or value independently via the `IList<T>.Add(T value)` method.

You should be able to reproduce this error by calling `Keys.Add(...)` or `Values.Add(...)`

Comment: Thanks @Haney. I feel the part that throws me off is how collection initializers work.
`Keys = {1}` and `Keys = new[]{1}` are treated differently by the compiler, but that isnt true for array initializers.
I guess with the `new[]` in there, I would have got the compile-time error I was looking for.

Comment: @sudheeshix yeah, I agree they are somewhat  confusing in how they sometimes just "interpret what you meant to do" for you.

Answer (score 0):

My initial query about the `SortedList` has now minimized to this concern about array, collection & object initializers, and the way the compiler interprets them differently. Thanks to @Haney again for the first answer to guide me towards this point of view, and to [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for these insights.

Here are some array and collection initializers:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
IList<int> c = { 1, 2, 3 };
IList<int> d = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

They all look kind of similar. Here, the compiler produces the exact same output for a & b. For c, we will get this compile-time error:

> Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types.
>   Try using a new expression instead.

which makes sense since we shouldn't use array initializers for collections. But then, d produces the exact same result as a & b. And I thought that was an array initializer as well. Apparently not.

Now consider this class

```
class MyCollectionContainer
{
    public int[] MyIntArray { get; set; }
    public IList<int> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

and this code that operates on it

```
var containerA = new MyCollectionContainer { MyIntArray = { 1, 2, 3 } };
var containerB = new MyCollectionContainer { MyIntArray = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 } };
var containerC = new MyCollectionContainer { MyList = { 1, 2, 3 } };
var containerD = new MyCollectionContainer { MyList = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 } };
```

containerA gives this compile-time error:

> Cannot initialize object of type 'int[]' with a collection initializer

For containerB, the compiler effectively converts it into this code:

```
MyCollectionContainer myCollectionContainer = new MyCollectionContainer();
myCollectionContainer.MyIntArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

For containerD, its pretty much the same, barring the fact that its another property that gets initialized:

```
MyCollectionContainer myCollectionContainer = new MyCollectionContainer();
myCollectionContainer.MyList = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

For containerC, the compiler morphs it into:

```
MyCollectionContainer myCollectionContainer = new MyCollectionContainer();
myCollectionContainer.MyList.Add(1);
myCollectionContainer.MyList.Add(2);
myCollectionContainer.MyList.Add(3);
```

This results in a run-time `NullReferenceException` since `MyList` is not initialized.

This means the only valid ways to initialize the collection container object here is containerB and containerD. To me, this clearly shows that object initializers are different when compared to array & collection initializers, in the way the compiler interprets them.